# How to estimate the amount of fuel leakage on a pressurized pipeline

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pipelines, piping

I need to identify the amount of leakage into the machinery space, as during an incident, the engineer started internal fuel transfer from a cargo tank to the fuel daily service tank.

The fuel pump capacity is 10 m<sup>3</sup>/hr, the delivery pressure is 0.75 bar (11 psi), and the head is around 2-meter height (pump location to tank inlet line height). The transfer process took about 15 minutes.

Nominal diameter piping outlet from the pump to Fuel Daily Tank is 40 mm, at the time of the transfer process, the engineer filled up to two tanks at the same time (image with Orange Highlighted).

However, due to negligence, there is another filling line the engineer forgot to isolate, which is to the Emcy Fuel Tank (image with Yellow Highlighted), with a piping nominal diameter 32mm, which lead to the leakage due to a torn gasket. The opening area of the leakage is approx 3 mm x 30 mm, since there is another isolation valve at the Emcy Fuel Tank, the fuel only leaked at the flange joint.

So during the fuel transfer process, there was a total of three openings on the line, which is two piping with a nominal 40 mm and another one a leaked area 3 mm x 30 mm.

Please refer to the attached screenshot diagram. Engine room temperature is around 37 °C, assuming no temperature change in fuel and pressure at 0.75 bar. I would like to estimate the amount of fuel that leaked into the machinery space through the leaky flange during the 15-minute transfer process.

[image]